# Jenkinsfile Syntax error for shell script

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I tried to append an sh script inside my jenkinsfile, however I'm getting this kind of syntax error even though `(` are properly encoded. Below is my `if`-`else` block script:

```java
// Display Users with permission rights
if (url_permission_type.contains('/api/permissions/users')) {
  userLogin = jsonGroupUserlist.users.login
  userName = jsonGroupUserlist.users.name
  userEmail = jsonGroupUserlist.users.email
  userPermission = jsonGroupUserlist.users.permissions

  index_users = 0
  for (String usrLogin: userLogin) {
    usrName = userName.get(index_users)
    usrEmail = userEmail.get(index_users)
    usrPermission = userPermission.get(index_users)

    if (usrEmail == null) {
      usrEmail = 'N/A'
      if (usrPermission) {
        sh(script: 'echo ' + project + ',' + usrLogin + ',' + usrName + ',' + usrEmail + ',' + usrPermission + ' >> SBI_' + params.permission_type.toString() + 'Access_Rights_Matrix.csv ')
        echo "SBI PROJECT: ${project} | ${usrLogin} | ${usrName.toString()} | ${usrEmail.toString()} | PERMISSIONS: ${usrPermission.toString()}"
      }
    } else {
      if (usrPermission) {
        sh(script: 'echo ' + project + ',' + usrLogin + ',' + usrName + ',' + usrEmail + ',' + usrPermission + ' >> SBI_' + params.permission_type.toString() + 'Access_Rights_Matrix.csv ')
        echo "SBI PROJECT: ${project} | ${usrLogin} | ${usrName.toString()} | ${usrEmail.toString()} | PERMISSIONS: ${usrPermission.toString()}"
      }
    }
    index_users++
  }
  echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
}
```

Error:

> @tmp/durable-3b9a6b0b/script.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Answer (score 0):

I dont fine any error your code but there may be error in other place of you code you can use ide like vscode that help you to detect and remove errors. It's possible that the syntax error is related to a missing or misplaced parenthesis in the shell script code. Or if the code block is not enclosed in a function or script block, that could also cause a syntax error since shell scripts require a top-level function or script block.

Comment: Hello @Sunil the error has been solved by Amit AB, thanks for your help man! I appreciate it :)